# What size of interface images I should use for IOS in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am not using Unity GUI for UI of my games. 
UI is building using Unity's planes.

In UI I have button size(100x100) with texture (size 100x100) and scale (1,1)
What size of texture I should use in iOS application for same button (size 100x100)
(Usually in iOS application use 2x size of texture (200x200))

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically scale the planes you created by attaching a script to the plane so they can handle various iPhone/iPad resolutions. Figuring out what works best is mostly based off opinion through testing.

```
start()
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Screen.width / 100, Screen.height / 100, 1);
```